# Problem with rendering data and heavy data loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

The first problem is that when **getDetails(‘multiple’, ‘2’)** function is called inside *HTML*, it takes some time until de data is displayed from **v-for**.

[image]

The second problem is that when I call the **console.log(userDetails)** from inside of **anotherFunction()** I got the **undefined** answer. It doesn’t wait for the **this.getDetails(‘multiple’, ‘1’)** to execute completely.

How can I improve the time for rendering, or should I use another way to display de data?
How can I make the second function to wait until the first function is complete?

> VUE version: 2.7.10

```html
  <div id="app">
    <p v-for="item in userDetails">item is displayed</p> // 
    <button @click="anotherFunction()">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
```

```js
    <script>
    export default {
     name: 'App',
     data: {
      userDetails: []
     }
    }

    // axios function
    getDetails(actionType, idUser) {
     axios.post("https://example.com/link", {
      Username: username
     }).then(response => {
         const result = response.data;

        // push data into variable
        this.userDetails.push(result[0])

     }).catch(error => {
         this.showError('Error', 4000);
         console.error('Error:' + error);
     });

    // another function from where I want to call the axios function
    anotherFunction() {
     this.getDetails('multiple', '1')

    // call the userDetails into another function will output "undefined"
    console.log(this.userDetails);
    }
```

Comment: Should you be doing `console.log(this.userDetails)` instead of just `userDetails`?

Comment: @blackcityhenry you right. In my code I did it the right way, but when I transcripted here I forgot.